# Trouble resizing bootstrap 3 box to fit with image

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please see the first image below.

[image]

This is working great and is how I want it to look. However when the browser resizes it then looks like this.

[image]

As you can see the white background of the text block is bigger than of the image block. I want the image block to be the same height as the text block but unfortunately this is not working. I am using Bootstrap 3 to develop this and you can see my code for this below:

```
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding:0;">
                <img src="core/img/abb[square].jpg" class="img-responsive">
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-9" style="background:#fff; height:218px; padding:7px 25px;">
                <h2><a class="a-cl">Page title</a> <small>2.1 miles away</small></h2>

                <p>Text content, summary of page here.</p>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Subscribed <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="margin-left:4px;"></i></a>
              </div>    
          </div>
        </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. As you can see I have manually defined the height on `<div class="col-sm-9">` and set `height:218px`. This obviously will not work dynamically as the page resizes.

**Summary: I am looking for an effective way of making sure the height of the text block is the same as the image block using bootstrap 3.**

Comment: also, you don't need col-md-12 around the col-sm, it will automatically do that, when you nest without rows it will mess up your padding and margins and you should not use inline styles. Do not insert a column inside a column without a surrounding row around the 12 (anything that adds to 12) but in this case don't need any col-12-* around your columns.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is with intrinsic ratios, it's not like the comments I made. However, the comment about the rows and columns and nesting are correct.

[image]

## DEMO: http://jsbin.com/zodama/1/

http://jsbin.com/zodama/1/edit

**Requires: jquery.matchHeight-min.js**

- https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

jQuery (when the script is installed):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.my-row [class*="col-"]').matchHeight();
  
});
```

---

The CSS, some of which is the aspect ratio and some of which is Bootstrap grid manipulation based on intimate knowledge of how it works.

```
.my-row {
    border: 10px solid #ddd;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: center;
}
.image img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.my-row [class*="col-"] {
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .my-row {
        border: 10px solid #ddd; /* remove this it's in the global */
        text-align: left;
    }
    .my-row [class*="col-"] {
        padding: 0;
        min-height: 220px;
    }
    .my-row [class*="col-"]:last-child {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .image img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out;
        transition: all 2s ease-out;
    }
    .image img {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    .image {
        position: relative;
        height: 0;
        padding-top: 56.25%;
    }
}


@media (min-width:992px) { 
    .my-row [class*="col-"] {
        min-height: 250px;
    }

}

@media (min-width:1200px) { 
    .my-row [class*="col-"] {
        min-height: 275px;
    }

}
```

---

HTML

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row my-row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 image">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/sports"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
           <h2><a class="a-cl">Page title</a> <small>2.1 miles away</small></h2>
           <p>Text content, summary of page here.</p>
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Subscribed <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a>
        </div>
     </div>
 <div class="row my-row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 image">
       <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/city"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
       <h2><a class="a-cl">Page title</a> <small>2.1 miles away</small></h2>
       <p>Text content, summary of page here.</p>
       <p>Text content, summary of page here.</p>
       <p>Text content, summary of page here.</p>
       <p>Text content, summary of page here.</p>
       <p>Text content, summary of page here.</p>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Subscribed <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a>
    </div>
 </div>
```